# Simply Connected Spaces and Surprising Homotopy: Extending Maps to Disks

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have an intriguing question. There's a proposition or exercise stating that if $X$ is a simply connected space, then the map $f: S^1 \longrightarrow X$ can be continuously extended to a disk $D^2$.

On the other hand, we know that if $f$ is null-homotopic, it can also be extended to $D^2$. Utilizing this insight, I will employ it to establish the previously mentioned proposition.

So to prove this proposition, it suffices to show that $f$ is null-homotopic. Let $(0,1)$ be a point in $S^1$, and consider the constant map $c_{f(0,1)}: S^1 \longrightarrow X$, defined as $c_{f(0,1)}(x,y) = f(0,1)$ for all $(x,y) \in S^1$.

Now, take a homotopy $H: S^1 \times [0,1] \longrightarrow X$, defined as $H((x,y), t) = f(tx, 1-t+ty)$. We observe that $H((x,y), 0) = f(0,1) = c_{f(0,1)}(x,y)$ and $H((x, y), 1) = f(x,y)$. Thus, $f$ is null-homotopic, and consequently, it is extended to $D^2$.

Surprisingly, the proof doesn't explicitly rely on the assumption that $X$ is simply connected. Is there something missing, or is there an inherent reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is incorrect, since the homotopy $H$ is not well-defined. You want to calculate $f(tx,1-t+ty)$ for arbitrary $t\in[0,1]$ and $(x,y)\in S^1$. But $f$ is only defined on $S^1$. If $t\neq0,1$ and $y\neq1$ we have $(tx,1-t+ty)\notin S^1$, hence you cannot calculate $f(tx,1-t+ty)$.

Hint for a correct approach: A continuous map $f\colon S^1\to X$ can be interpreted as the element of $\pi_1(X,f(0,1))$ given by
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\tilde f\colon[0,1]&\to& X\\
t&\mapsto& f(\sin(2\pi\operatorname i\cdot t),\cos(2\pi\operatorname i\cdot t))
\end{array}
$$
If $\pi_1(X,f(0,1))=0$ there exists a path-homotopy $\tilde H\colon[0,1]\times[0,1]\to X$ from $\tilde f$ to the constant path at $f(0,1)$. One can upgrade this path-homotopy to a homotopy $H\colon S^1\times[0,1]\to X$ that shows that $f$ is null-homotopic.

Comment: You are exactly correct,  is there any hint to show  simply-connectedness of$ X$ immediately implies that $ f$
 is null-homotopic?

Comment: What definition of simply-connectedness do you use?

Comment: The definition that I use is that $X$ is simply connected iff its path connected and its fundamental group is trivial.

Comment: I have added a hint in the original answer.

Comment: Yes thank very much.